# Will creating a texmf tree structure cause harm on my setup?

Tags: packages, ubuntu

I have an Ubuntu machine and I'm using the Atom text editor to edit and compile .tex files.  It's able to use all of the standard packages, so it must have them stored somewhere.  Now I want to download and install a new .sty file, however, I'm not able to find the directory where the existing ones are stored.  When I run `sudo texhash` I get

```
texhash: Updating /usr/local/share/texmf/ls-R... 
texhash: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXLIVEDIST... 
texhash: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXMFMAIN... 
texhash: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R... 
texhash: Done.
```

However, in each location I don't find any .sty files.  When I run `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME` I get

```
/home/billybob/texmf
```

However, when I navigate to `/home/billybob` there is no folder named texmf there.  I've seen instructions elsewhere about creating a tree structure to store .sty files and I guess also .tex files--however, I'm worried that if I do, Atom will look only there for any `\usepackage` commands and therefore I might lose access to my standard packages.

Should I just go ahead and manually make the tree structure?  Or should I find where Atom is accessing the already stored .sty files?

Comment: look at the log of any file you produce, the full path for every input file is given in there. Your editor Atom isn't really involved, it does not need to know where packages are installed, it os simply a matter of the tex setup.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Worked like a charm!  But I saved my new .sty file in the sub-directory called "base".  Probably a mistake, but not sure what else to do.  Ran it, and it said it couldn't find the file.  Should I save this file somewhere else in the tree structure?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see a lot of other pages suggesting to put it in the "local" subdirectory but I don't have one ... I have "locality", would that be the same?

Comment: don't put it in base (that's my job:-) and it will be removed if you ever update. why don't you just create the directory `/home/billybob/texmf/tex/latex/whatever`  and put `whatever.sty` in there?

Comment: Wasn't sure it would automatically know to look in newly created folders. I made the folder `/home/billybob/texmf/tex/latex/fitch` and put the file `fitch.sty` in it. Re-ran a simple test `.tex` file and it says it still can't find it. @David Carlisle

Comment: All of this actually relates to the way that Ubuntu installs texlive from its package manager, and the way that the installed textlive sets up its environment. Suggestion: Open your home directory. Make hidden files visible (to do this, in the file manager menu, View: Show Hidden Files). Do you see a directory named .texmf or .texmf-local there? Notice the dot in front. If so, open and have a look inside. It may be that your user-level (local) text structure goes in there. Be sure to use the directory structure.

Comment: Simplfying (quite) a bit, we could say that each host computer has, under TeX Live, three “important” texmf trees: the “distribution” tree (`$TEXMFDIST`), which should be never directly tampered with, the "local” tree (`$TEXMFLOCAL`), where you should put local additions to, or even replacements for, standard packages that you want to share among all users of the local machine (requires admin priviledges, of course), and each user’s “personal” tree (`$TEXMFHOME`), for additions/replacements of that user only.  Files placed in the latter become immediately visible, the former two need indexing.

Comment: @RobtA I actually don't have either of those, but I do have `texmf-var`.  Inside of this is only the folder `fonts` inside of which is only the folder `tfm` which has three things, blah, blah, blah, not sure what to do with this.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti from that description I figured I should find `$TEXMFHOME`.  When I echo it, it returns a blank.

Comment: The "var" folders, wherever they are, contain things that will change from time to time, even if you do not change the software. For example, a browser's cache is likely to be found in a "var" folder. Generally, do not touch the "var" folders, as they are handled automatically. Exception: Within texlive, the texmf-var contains a luatex-cache that sometimes should be deleted. No harm, as it is rebuilt. Otherwise, forget about var.

Comment: Try this: Open a Terminal. Type `which mktexlsr` That should return the path to a key TeX executable. Go to that folder, and look upwards in the folder tree until you see something interesting. If you do find texmf-local or equivalent, you might need sudo privileges to put a *.sty file there. Then run mktexlsr. But if the `which` command does not succeed, there is a deeper problem.

Comment: @RobtA `which mktexlsr` returns `/usr/bin/mktexlsr`.  The folder is huge, has thousands of things in it.  Only looked in the vicinity of `tex...` named stuff.  Nothing said `texmf` or anything like it.  I ran `ls -a *local*` and it returned a few things but none of them had the letters `tex` in them.

Comment: Ah. Then your texlive installation is "not what I was expecting." Well then, try this: Use your file manager's search feature to look for files names "ls-r". That's the whole file name, no extension. (ell ess dash r) See where those files are located. They should be within the folders of interest. But if that does not work, then I am completely at a loss.

Comment: @RobtA I So I haven't found any such file using `find / -name ls-r` or using the files application to search.  Would it help to do some new install of texlive?  I added a ppa for texlive and ran an install command, but still don't find a `ls-r` file.

Comment: @Addem: `echo $TEXMFHOME` won’t work (it’s *not* a shell variable), `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFHOME` is the way to ask for it; and you did say in your question that, on your system, it returns `/home/billybob/texmf` (which looks like what I’d expect), didn’t you?  So, I cannot explain why your [`fitch.sty` example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365770/will-creating-a-texmf-tree-structure-cause-harm-on-my-setup?noredirect=1#comment901362_365770), above, does not work…  If you did exactly what you reported, then `\usepackage{fitch}` *should* find your file.